# Finding the Output file in CodeBlocks

Tags: c++, c, codeblocks

I wanted to know where the output of CodeBlocks is located (i.e whatever information is shown in the Debugger Window.)
And also i wanted to export this output file to a text or xml or an html file.
Can someone please suggest how this process should be carried out.

Comment: It probably is not saved in a file.

Comment: Which version of CB are you using? I seem to remember that versions 17.12 and earlier exported an html file with debugging errors to the bin/Debug folder. Now I use version 2020.03 and I can't verify.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are searching `freopen()` function in c++. In that case you can try **freopen('example.txt','w',stdout)** to write your outputs in example.txt file.

This may help you- http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/freopen/